# Updated 64-Bit Xamarin Android App gets overridden by old 32-Bit version

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, 64-bit

As (demanded) by Google, I added x64-Bit Support to our Xamarin.Forms app. When I sideloaded it onto our test-devices running the currently existing store version, I couldn't finish the install.

After uninstalling the current app, the new one installed just fine and everything worked as expected.

I forwarded the app package to our testers, told them to uninstall the old app and called it a day.

Today I learned, that the Play Store Version (v1.1.0) silently updated the current app (v1.2+) back to the old version.
I confirmed this via sideloading.

In my Android options I have two build targets:

- armeabi-v7a (the old one)
- arm64-v8a (the newly added one)

I thought, the device would select the right architecture and do its thing. How come, that the old app with obviously lower version number can update the new, but not the other way around?

Did I mess something up? Missed some settings or set the wrong ones?

If I inspect my built apk, the folders for each architecture are side by side, just as expected. The right .so files are present.
I'm working on Visual Studio 2017.

[Android Build Config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zGhPO.png)

Comment: It is the Version Number and not the Version Name that determines whether an app can be updated or not. Make sure the Version Number in your local build is newer than the one in Play Store.

Comment: Thanks! Too obvious. One of the git commits has messed with the version number and I didn't check it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should pay attention to the app's [versionCode](https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/versioning#appversioning).

> A positive integer used as an internal version number. This number is used only to determine whether one version is more recent than another, with higher numbers indicating more recent versions. This is not the version number shown to users; that number is set by the `versionName` setting, below. The Android system uses the `versionCode` value to protect against downgrades by preventing users from installing an APK with a lower `versionCode` than the version currently installed on their device.
>
> The value is a positive integer so that other apps can programmatically evaluate it, for example to check an upgrade or downgrade relationship. You can set the value to any positive integer you want, however you should make sure that each successive release of your app uses a greater value. You cannot upload an APK to the Play Store with a `versionCode` you have already used for a previous version.